# What are the `ResourceFunction`s that should be included in the official release?

Tags: resourcefunction

[Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) is indeed a  treasury with many valuable functions. And I personally enjoy trying out all the new ones every Friday night after receiving its newsletter.

Although we can easily load the functionality via `ResourceFunction`, lack of local help page sometimes can be annoying.

Just out of curiosity, what are the `ResourceFunction`s that should be included in the official release?

Comment: _what are the ResourceFunctions that should be included in the official release?_ This is an opinion based question.  Whatever functions end up in the next release is entirely up to what Wolfram decide. I could point to some good and useful functions, but what I think has very little bearing on what goes in the next release.

Comment: This might be appropriate, however, for the Wolfram Community forum.